# Passing user defined object to IoptionsMonitor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a working code like below where my business logic is consuming configuration like -

```
public MyBusinessLogic(MyConfiguration _myConfiguration)
{
   // using _myConfiguration
}
```

configuration is passed through startup.cs like

```
public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    base.ConfigureServices(services);

    var **myConfiguration** = new MyConfiguration();
    Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyConfiguration )).Bind(myConfiguration);
    myConfiguration.value1= "123";
    myConfiguration.value2= "456";
    services.AddSingleton(myConfiguration);
}
```

Now I want to use myConfiguration using IOptionsMonitor for autoreload feature. Something like -

```
public MyBusinessLogic(IOptionsMonitor<MyConfiguration> _myConfiguration)
{
   // using _myConfiguration.CurrentValue
}
```

We can pass generic object(which is created/injected by asp.net) like-

```
// Add realtime configuration support
services.Configure<MyConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("MyConfiguration"));
```

So my question is how to pass the user-defined object i.e. **myConfiguration** to IoptionsMonitor and whether it is possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it without binding it to `IConfiguration`:

```
services.Configure<MyConfiguration>(myCfg => {
  /* here myCfg is an already created instance of `MyConfiguration`, you can set its properties or do whatever, e.g: */
  myCfg.Property1 = myConfiguration.Property1;
  myCfg.Property2 = myConfiguration.Property2;
 
});
```

And you'll receive the object in the `IOptionsMonitor<MyConfiguration>.CurrentValue`.

Notice that you don't get any kind of detection change there (it can be implemented but that's way outside the scope of this question), so I'd rather use `IOptions` and not `IOptionsMonitor`.

Comment: Thanks, can you point me towards doing any article or page having change detection support also? So I like some properties to be hardcoded(which currently I am getting from SF configuration) and others to be dynamic.

Comment: @AnujNautiyal for change detection, you use changetokens ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/change-tokens?view=aspnetcore-5.0 ). Inside the delegated passed to `Configure<MyConfiguration>` you could load your configuration section and apply whatever properties you want to it.